# How to get value of some edit text in recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have some items in recycler view and each item has an edit text, how I get the value from each edit text and pass it to the previous fragment, I've tried some solution but none of them really work for me.
here is my adapter:

```
interface OnUpdateData{
    fun dataUpdate (data: List<AcceptanceDifferent>?)
}

class EditAcceptDifferentAdapter(private val itemAcceptance: List<DistributionPlanItems>,
                                 private val action: OnUpdateData) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<EditAcceptDifferentAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {

    private var selectedItem  = mutableSetOf<AcceptanceDifferent>()
    private val selectedId = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    private lateinit var listData: ArrayList<AcceptanceDifferent>

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): MainViewHolder {
        return MainViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_edit_different, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return itemAcceptance.size
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder,position: Int) {
        val items = itemAcceptance[position]
        if (!items.expiredDate.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val format2 = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            val localeID = Locale("in", "ID")
            val simpleDateFormat2 = SimpleDateFormat(format2, localeID)
            val date = simpleDateFormat2.parse(items.expiredDate)
            holder.expiredDate.text = "Expired Date: ${simpleDateFormat2.format(date)}"
        }

        holder.batchCode.text = "Batch Code: ${items.inventory?.batchCode}"
        holder.medName.text = items.medicine?.name
        holder.batchCode.text = items.inventory?.batchCode
        listData = ArrayList()

        listData.add(AcceptanceDifferent(id = items.distPlanItemId, actualReceivedPackageQuantity = 0))
        action.dataUpdate(listData)

    }


    inner class MainViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val medName = view.textMedName1
        val batchCode = view.tvBatchCode
        val expiredDate = view.textMedExpiredDate1
        val qty = view.editTextQty
    }


}
```

I've made an interface to pass the data but in my code, it doesn't work

thank you

Comment: do you want to get the value whenever each populated in the list?

Comment: What `AcceptanceDifferent` looks like?

Comment: `data class AcceptanceDifferent(
    private val id: Int?,
    private val actualReceivedPackageQuantity: Int?
)`

@Md.Asaduzzaman, the Id is from dataset, and actualReceivedPackageQuantity from the editText

Comment: Is your `EditText` returns only number?

Comment: yes, how I pass it into an array?

Answer (score 1):

You have to watch text changed in your `EditText` and do your operation there and then notify the listener to check the data. Check below implementation. Hope this will help you.

```
// You have to initialize listData outside of onBindViewHolder
listData = ArrayList()

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder,position: Int) {
    val items = itemAcceptance[position]

    // Other code here

    holder.batchCode.text = "Batch Code: ${items.inventory?.batchCode}"
    holder.medName.text = items.medicine?.name
    holder.batchCode.text = items.inventory?.batchCode
    //listData = ArrayList()    

    holder.qty.doAfterTextChanged { text ->
        val data = listData.find { it.id == items.distPlanItemId }
        val value = text?.toString()?.toInt()

        if(data == null) {
            listData.add(AcceptanceDifferent(id = items.distPlanItemId, actualReceivedPackageQuantity = value))
        } else {
            data.actualReceivedPackageQuantity = value
        }

        action.dataUpdate(listData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a listener in the EditText to call the data update.

Let's say you want to receive the updated text in your fragment every time that the user types anything in any EditText. In that case you will need a `TextWatcher` in your editText that will call your `action`.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder,position: Int) {
    //...
    // Assuming you want every update in the `qty` value
    holder.qty.afterTextChanged { input ->
        action.onQtyUpdated(input)
    }
}
```

Where the `afterTextChanged` is an extension function defined below:

```
fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
        }
    })
}
```